# Writing data to disc in seperate thread (in parallel)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, saving-data

I would like to start a function multiple times in a loop that each time acquire and image from a camera and writes the image to disc without the loop waiting for this process to finish. So every time this function is called it runs in parallel with the loop that started the function such that I can continue doing other time sensitive stuff in the meantime.

I have made this example which make the first "execution" of the function run in parallel with the loop and then fails the second time as I cannot .start() it twice. Can this be achieved by other means?

Example (original post - updated below)

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

def imacq():
    print('acquiring image...')
    time.sleep(1.8)
    print('saved image...')
    return

# Start image acqusition and writing to disc thread
imacq_thread = threading.Thread(target=imacq)

starttime = time.time()
sig_arr = np.zeros(100)
tim_arr = np.zeros(100)
image_cycles = 5
running = True
flag = True
for cycles in range(1,20):
    print(cycles)
    if cycles%image_cycles == 0:
        if flag is True:
            imacq_thread.start() # this works well the first time as intended
            # imacq() # this does not work as everything is paused until imacp() returns
            flag = False
    else:
        flag = True
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

EDIT: After feedback from Sylvaus:
I have made two different versions for triggering a function that eventually will be used to acquire and store and image on the drive in parallel with a main script that decides the time to send a trigger/execute the function. One version is based on Sylvaus' answer (threading) and another is based on multiprocessing.

Example based on Sylvaus's answer (Threading):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def imacq():
    print('taking image')
    n = 10000
    np.ones((n, n))*np.ones((n, n))  # calculations taking time
    print('saving image')
    return


sig_arr = np.zeros(100)
tim_arr = np.zeros(100)
image_cycles = 20
max_cycles = 100
freq = 10
cycles = 1
sigSign = 1

running = True
flag = True
timeinc = []
tic = time.time()
tic2 = tic
timeinc = np.zeros(max_cycles)
starttime = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    while running:
        t = time.time()-starttime
        tim_arr[:-1] = tim_arr[1:]
        tim_arr[-1] = t
        signal = np.sin(freq*t*(2.0*np.pi))
        sig_arr[:-1] = sig_arr[1:]
        sig_arr[-1] = signal

        time.sleep(0.00001)
        # Calculate cycle number
        sigSignOld = sigSign
        sigSign = np.sign(sig_arr[-1]-sig_arr[-2])
        if sigSign == 1 and sigSignOld != sigSign:
            timeinc[cycles] = time.time()-tic
            cycles += 1
            print('cycles: ', cycles, ' time inc.: ', str(timeinc[cycles-1]))
            tic = time.time()

        if cycles%image_cycles == 0:
            if flag is True:
                # The function is submitted and will be processed by a
                # a thread as soon as one is available
                executor.submit(imacq)
                flag = False
        else:
            flag = True
        if cycles >= max_cycles:
            running = False

print('total time: ', time.time()-tic2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
plt.plot(timeinc)
```

Example based on multiprocessing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Lock


def trig_resp(running, trigger, p_count, pt, lock):
    while running.value == 1:  # note ".value" on each sharedctype variable
        time.sleep(0.0001)  # sleeping in order not to load CPU too excessively
        if trigger.value == 1:
            with lock:  # lock "global" variable before wrtting to it
                trigger.value = 0  # reset trigger
            tic = time.time()
            # Do a calculation that takes a significant time
            n = 10000; np.ones((n, n))*np.ones((n, n))
            with lock:
                pt.value = time.time() - tic  # calculate process time
                p_count.value += 1  # count number of finished processes
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize shared values (global accross processes/sharedctype).
    # Type 'i': integer, type 'd': double.
    trigger = Value('i', 0)  # used to trigger execution placed in trig_resp()
    running = Value('i', 1)  # A way to break the loop in trig_resp()
    p_count = Value('i', 0)  # process counter and flag that process is done
    pt = Value('d', 0.0)  # process time of latest finished process
    lock = Lock() # lock object used to avoid raise conditions when changing "global" values.
    p_count_old = p_count.value
    p1 = Process(target=trig_resp, args=(running, trigger, p_count, pt, lock))
    p1.start()  # Start process

    # A "simulated" sinusiodal signal
    array_len = 50
    sig_arr = np.zeros(array_len)  # Signal array
    tim_arr = np.zeros(array_len)  # Correpsonding time array
    freq = 10  # frequency of signal

    # trigger settings
    im_int = 20  # cycle interval for triggering (acquiring images)
    max_cycles = 100  # max number of cycles before stopping main

    # initializing counters etc.
    cycles = 1  # number of cycles counted
    sigSign = 1  # sign of signal gradient
    flag = 1  # used to only set trigger once for the current cycle count
    trigger_count = 0  # counts how many times a trigger has been set

    tic = time.time()
    tic2 = tic
    timeinc = np.zeros(max_cycles) # Array to keep track of time used for each main loop run
    starttime = time.time()
    while running.value == 1:
        time.sleep(0.00001)  # mimics sample time (real world signal)
        t = time.time()-starttime  # local time
        signal = np.sin(freq*t*(2.0*np.pi))  # simulated signal
        # Keeping the latest array_len values (FIFO) of t and signal.
        tim_arr[:-1] = tim_arr[1:]
        tim_arr[-1] = t
        sig_arr[:-1] = sig_arr[1:]
        sig_arr[-1] = signal

        if p_count.value == p_count_old + 1:  # process have finished
            print('Process counter: ', p_count.value,  'process_time: ', pt.value)
            p_count_old = p_count.value

        # Calculate cycle number by monotoring sign of the gradient
        sigSignOld = sigSign  # Keeping track of previous signal gradient sign
        sigSign = np.sign(sig_arr[-1]-sig_arr[-2])  # current gradient sign
        if sigSign == 1 and sigSignOld == -1:  # a local minimum just happened
            timeinc[cycles] = time.time()-tic
            cycles += 1
            print('cycles: ', cycles, ' time inc.: ', str(timeinc[cycles-1]))
            tic = time.time()
            flag = 1

        if cycles % im_int == 0 and flag == 1:
            if cycles > 0:
                if trigger_count > p_count.value:
                    print('WARNING: Process: ', p_count.value,
                          'did not finish yet. Reduce freq or increase im_int')
                trigger.value = 1
                trigger_count += 1
                print('Trigger number: ', trigger_count)
                flag = 0

        if cycles >= max_cycles:
            running.value = 0

    print('total cycle time: ', time.time()-tic2)

    # Print the process time of the last run
    if p_count.value < max_cycles//im_int:
        if p_count.value == p_count_old + 1:
            print('process counter: ', p_count.value,  'process_time: ', pt.value)
            p_count_old = p_count.value

    print('total process time: ', time.time()-tic2)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    plt.plot(timeinc)
```

I am on a windows 10 laptop so the timing (time increment in each loop of the main while loop "while running...:") is dependent on what else is happening on my computer, but the version based on multiprocessing seems less sensitive to this than the one based on threading. However the one based on multiprocessing is not very elegant and I am suspecting that a smarter solution is possible (simpler and less easy to make a mistake) that can achieve the same or better (consistent time increments with lower load on the CPU).

I have attached graphs of the time increments I get here for the Multiprocess and Threading example, respectively here: [image: Multiprocess example] 
[image: Threading example]

Any feedback on improving the two solutions is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are really trying to do, or what the question is. You appear to want to read from a camera as fast as possible and to want to write some frames to disk occasionally, without impacting the acquisition. If so, you need to measure your max acquisition rate by reading and discarding frames - you can never do better than this. Then you need to determine how much data each frame is and how many you want to store. You may be able to hold them in RAM in a list without going to disk. You need to see how long it takes to write one to disk.

Comment: If multiprocessing, you need to see how long it takes to pass the frame to another process. You need to know how many CPU cores and how much RAM you have.

Comment: You may find it's quicker to JPEG compress your images and the smaller size allows you to store them in RAM. It may be quicker to write the frames to a video.

Comment: Hi Mark Setchell. I want to trigger a camera at a very specific time which I calculate in the main program based on some signal coming in from a DAQ. There are plenty of time between images I acquire to store it before acquiring the next image, but I cannot have the main program wait for this to happen as it needs to read and process the signal from the DAQ with out interuptions.

Comment: What's a `DAQ` please?

Comment: Hi Mark, I mean an external data acquisition device which I interface with through Python. I monitor an analogue signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details of your acquisition devices, data rates and volumes don't seem to be very clear but I get the impression that the issue is that you want to acquire one signal as fast as possible and want to get an image captured and written to disk as soon as possible whenever that signal is *"interesting"* but without delaying the next acquisition of the signal.

So, it seems there is minimal data exchange necessary between the main signal acquisition process and the image capture process. IMHO, that suggests multiprocessing (therefore no GIL) and use of a queue (no large volumes of data to pickle) to communicate between the two processes.

So, I would be looking at this type of setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support

def ImageCapture(queue):
    while True:
        # Wait till told to capture image - message could contain event reference number
        item = queue.get()
        if item == -1:
           break
        # Capture image and save to disk

def main():
    # Create queue to send image capture requests on
    queue = Queue(8)

    # Start image acquisition process
    p = Process(target=ImageCapture, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    # do forever
    #    acquire from DAQ
    #    if interesting
    #       queue.put(event reference number or filename)

    # Stop image acquisition process
    queue.put(-1)
    p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Some Windows thing
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

If the `ImageCapture()` process can't keep up, start two or more.

On my Mac, I measured a mean message delivery time on a queue of 32 microseconds, and a maximum latency of 120 microseconds over 1 million messages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark Setchell. I have done a new version of the process based solution I posted previously using your suggestion with Queue. It is equally fast when I time it with time.time() and as consistent. I suspect it might be faster although I cannot measure it. Also it is using a lot less CPU since I get rid of a while loop asking for changes in the global "trigger" value and fewer lines of code. I like that. How did you measure the delivery time to the queue?

Comment: I measured it by replacing the ImageCapture process by a dummy one with a request and a reply queue. It just receives messages from the request queue and replies on the reply queue. That gives me the *"round-trip time"* which I then saved in a list and plotted and calculated mean/max/stddev at the end. Note that I believe you are not that interested in the delay between asking the second process to grab a picture and when it actually does. I understood you were more interested in how soon the main task can get back to reading the analogue signal. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Did you use time.time() and did you do it on a windows machine? You are right it was not my original/main concern. It also seems to be plenty fast no matter what. So my follow up question was mainly for learning opportunity :-) I am taking images of something that moves and part of the task is to acquire the image when the object is at a certain location +- so it is relevant if the time between setting the trigger (queue.put()) and the camera actually acquiring the images is too large . So it would be nice if I can actually measure this and not just assume that it is fast enough

Comment: You can measure that too. Just get the time and send the time on the queue. Change the receiver to wait for a message on the queue and then subtract the received time from the current time. I don't have Windows, I use a Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects).This way, you can simply submit your tasks and they will be processed based on the type of Executor you are using.

I don't know what is in your `imacq`, so you may have to try `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` to find which one is the most fitting for your application.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def imacq():
    print('acquiring image...')
    time.sleep(1.8)
    print('saved image...')
    return

starttime = time.time()
sig_arr = np.zeros(100)
tim_arr = np.zeros(100)
image_cycles = 5
running = True
flag = True

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for cycles in range(1,20):
        print(cycles)
        if cycles%image_cycles == 0:
            if flag is True:
                # The function is submitted and will be processed by a 
                # a thread as soon as one is available
                executor.submit(imacq)
                flag = False
        else:
            flag = True
        time.sleep(0.4)
```

Comment: Hi Sylvaus, thanks for the answer. It brought me forward. I have added a new version based on your proposal and another one based on multiprocessing where the timing is a little better. Do you know if the "timing" issues I have with the threading solutions is related to Python's global interpreter lock, a windows thing, or something else?. I think it could be a more clean code if I could fix the Threading version than what I did with the multiprocessing version. I am new to Python.

Comment: The GIL is definitively responsible for the peaks you see on the graph. The thread trying to allocate the memory and do the matrix computation will for sure take some time but the question is how you will take the image. For example if the getting of the image use subprocess, then a thread will be fine since subprocess will create a new process, however if it is not the case then having a process doing the acquisition can be a good idea. You have a lot of available option, simply try them

Comment: Sylvaus, thanks again for the comments. I have at least one application in mind where I use a camera where the "driver runs out side of python" (I am not sure how to be accurate about this) where I assumed that your original threading based solution would work. However the camera/driver might be changed so I am not sure this would also be the case. Indeed there are many options that I am learning about and trying out :-) so far I think the least computational heavy process based one is a solution based on multiprocessing and queue as suggested by Mark Setchell.

Comment: No problem, something to note is that a simplified implementation of `ProcessPoolExecutor ` is pretty much Mark Setchell implementation with mulitple workers